# Batch script for search & replace without skipping empty line, '!' and ';'?

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, replace

Sorry, for bothering you for the (n+1)th time about search & replace with batch scripts.
I have text files (actually PS-files) (approx. 10kB-3MB) where I need to replace just a few numbers.

This should be easy, I thought.
I found quite a few scripts here on Stackoverflow but none of them worked properly so far. If I have overlooked THE "working one" please let me know.

The last one I tried:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set OutputFile=%1
set OutputFile=%OutputFile:"=%
set InputFile=%OutputFile%.tmp

set SearchString=636170656C6C6133
set ReplaceString=636170656C6C6134

rem write empty file
type NUL > %OutputFile%

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %InputFile%"') do (
 SET string=%%A
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 SET modified=!string:%SearchString%=%ReplaceString%!

 echo !modified!>>%OutputFile% 
 endlocal
)
del %InputFile%
```

First of all, it seems to be pretty(!) slow. I can see on disk how the file size increases.
The occurrences of the numbers seem to be replaced. However, the file is altered, which I easily can see from the different file size. As far as I can see, empty lines, exclamation marks and lines beginning with semicolon are skipped. This is messing up my file completely.
How to avoid this?
If I do the same thing with Perl I really get only the numbers altered, nothing else. However, I don't want to and cannot use Perl. I also don't want to use other extra programs or Windows-Powershell, since it should work on older systems too.
Is there any way to achieve this with a simple Windows batch script?
Thanks!

Comment: The problems you encounter are inherent to batch solutions. They maybe overcome by solutions adapted to your input file but you didn't extend on that. I think j-/vbscript framed in a batch can help you. See [jrepl.bat from dbenham on dostips.com](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044)

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, so I understand that this is not possible with a simple batch script, correct? Maybe could it be done with altering the file first, i.e. like masking `'!'` and `';'` or adding e.g. `'#'` at each beginning of the line and then substracting it later again? If possible I want to avoid javascript, vbs-script or thelike.

Comment: Well empty lines may be overcome with using find/findstring numbering the lines, the `!` with using a sub or a pseudo call instead of setlocal enabledelayedexpansion the `;` with defining a different eol char but this all won't speed up execution.

Comment: Are you attempting to strip the surround quotes from the file name with this set of code: `set OutputFile=%OutputFile:"=%`.  How about you just do it this way. `set OutputFile=%~1`

Comment: @Squashman, basically yes. If there are more elegant ways they are welcome. Learned again something. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following is a working bat script that should not make any changes other than the desired number change:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "out=%~1"
set "in=%out%.tmp"

set "find=636170656C6C6133"
set "repl=636170656C6C6134"

>"%out%" (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%in%"') do (
    set "str=%%A"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "str=!str:*:=!"
    if defined str set "str=!str:%find%=%repl%!"
    echo(!str!
    endlocal
  )
)
del "%in%"
```

Changes I have made:

- Use `%~1` to remove enclosing parentheses. Though technically, that is not necessary. Something like `echo test >"someName.txt".new` will work just fine.
- FOR /F strips empty lines. I used FINDSTR to prefix each line with the line number, followed by a colon. Now there are no empty lines.
- I use an extra variable expansion find/replace with `*` to remove the line number prefix.
- Variable expansion find/replace will fail if a string is empty (undefined variable). So I verify the variable is defined before doing find/replace.
- ECHOing an empty line, or line containing only white space, will result in `ECHO is off.` output. This is solved by using `echo(`
- It takes time to initialize redirection, and your loop does this every iteration, which slows things down. I improved performance by enclosing the entire FOR loop in parentheses and redirecting only once.

You still may see a slight file size change for any of the following reasons

- If the input has \n line terminators instead of \r\n.
- If the last line of input is not terminated by \r\n. The script terminates all lines with \r\n, regardless what the input had.

The script will fail if any line contains a null byte, or if any line is >~8k length.

***I hate editing text files with batch - it is complicated code, slow, and even the best possible solution still has significant limitations.***

I recommend you use [JREPL.BAT - a command line regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file or special configuration is needed.

The tool is very powerful, with many options. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help.

Solving your problem with JREPL is trivial - you don't even need another script. The following command will work right from a command prompt:

```
jrepl 636170656C6C6133 636170656C6C6134 /f input.txt /o output.txt
```

Use CALL JREPL if you put the command within another batch script.

JREPL is way more powerful than what you need for this simple problem. But it is incredibly convenient, and once you have the utility, I suspect you will find many uses for it. Especially if you learn to use regular expressions, as well as the many JREPL options.

Comment: thank you for this detailed and clear answer. I always thought: there must be a better way I just don't see it. If you as an expert say that it's practically difficult, I really shouldn't try further and look for alternatives. Luckily, I noticed that the program creating the output is already using Python, so there will be no extra installation for me and others. A first python script is already working :-).
Although the answer is not the one I hoped for, but it clearly explains and tells me that I'd better go for another solution. So, +1 and the "solution" I have to accept. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I nevertheless tested your script. If you change the 4th line to:
`set "in=%out%.tmp"`  it works and is also faster. Thank you very much again! In my case, the input file has the same name as the output file just added with .tmp so that I can avoid renaming later as it is done with other scripts here on SO.

Comment: @theozh - Yes, that was a silly typo resulting from untested code, all fixed. You really should check out [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). It totally meets your need that it work on older machines. And it is much faster than any pure batch solution. The embedded JScript is natively supported by all versions of Windows, right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

A VBS script

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Text = Inp.readall
    Text = Replace(Text, "636170656C6C6133", "636170656C6C6134")
    outp.write Text
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo script.vbs < input.txt > Output.txt
```

You use the right tool for the job. Batch is for starting programs and copying files.

The above is suited to the file sizes given. However if we are getting up to 100s of MB then this code is better.

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Text = Inp.readline
    Text = Replace(Text, "636170656C6C6133", "636170656C6C6134")
    outp.writeline Text
Loop
```